# Can someone tell me the meter of the verses, chorus, and bridge in "A Night in Tunisia" by Ella Fitzgerald

Tags: jazz, meter

I have a project for my music class where I need to analyze a song and I am having trouble figuring out the meter of each section. Could someone help me out?

Comment: I recall answering this question a couple of months ago here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108256/ella-fitzgeralds-rendition-of-a-night-in-tunisia

Comment: I guess everybody's doing the same course ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Hey, at least SOMEONE is learning about this stuff! :-)